# Data structure for fast lookups with consistent indexing

Tags: c++, stdvector, unordered-map

My `data` are stored in a vector of custom objects and in this particular piece of software I'm interested in those that are `interesting`. I thus have a `std::vector<size_t> interesting;` where I store their indexes, so that when I call `data[ interesting[i] ]` I get the i-th interesting data object.

I need to specify here that `interesting` is an **unsorted** vector of indexes, so at the moment there isn't any clever trick I can use with the ordering of the elements in the original `data` ...

Now onto the problem:
These data are interesting because they have either property `A`, `B` or both and I need to store the value of that property (let's say it's a simple `double`) in another vector for fast retrieval.

I wonder how would I go about it! Which structure should I use for the properties?

Say `data.size() = 100` and `interesting.size() = 90` (much bigger, but easier to work with round numbers) and deleting the "un-interesting" data is not an option because they're used by other parts of the software.
I need in particular to be able to do fast lookups, neither `data` nor `interesting` will change in size as the software runs (only data values will) so insertion in the structures is a one-off cost at the beginning and won't impact performances as much as lookups will.

I have two solutions that came to mind:

- I could use a `std::unordered_map<size_t,double> A` and similar for B to store the index-property pairs, so I can search using `A.at(interesting[i])` to get the value of property `A` for the i-th interesting element.
  Because insertions won't happen at this stage anymore am I safe to assume this is O(1) ? This would be my preferred way.
- I could allocate a `std::vector<double> A ( data.size() );` to store these values and just call `A[ interesting[i] ]` as I do for the data; this ensures lookups are fast but I would:

  1. waste a LOT of memory as the size of `data` grows...in fact I'd waste a combined `data.size()` elements if we assume no overlap. For now `A` and `B` are just `double`, but if at any point I need to change their type into something larger ... I assume that a sparse vector with O(1) lookup doesn't exists, right?
  2. There's no bound checking here and god forbid I go and search for `A[3]` and `3` is not an interesting index! I'd need to insert my own checking overhead which will probably make so that lookups are not so fast anymore...

In short: I'm interested in a data structure for the properties `A` and `B` so that I can access those values [which are defined only for `interesting` data point] and know to which `data` value they correspond as well...

Can anybody think of a good solution for this problem? Hopefully I made myself clear enough!

---

A commenter asked for a code example, I don't have a working since I haven't figured out which data structure to use, but ideally I would simply want to do

```
std::vector<MyObject> data;
// ...
// get data and do stuff
// ...

std::vector<size_t> interesting;
// ...
// initialise interesting as a vector of indexes that refer to the data
// ...

// Now initialize the A property DS
std::vector<double> A ( data.size() ); // <--- this is what I'm questioning about
// maybe I'm better off with std::unordered_map<size_t,double> A ?

// so that (once initialised) I can quickly do
size_t i = 5;
std::cout << "Data point " << data[ interesting[i] ] << 
    " has a property A's value of " << A[ interesting[i] ] << std::endl;
// for evey i I want
```

Comment: May be you could post a code example to make your problem clear, I can't understand it. Could be you just need to learn about `boost::multi_index`.

Comment: The data vecotr does not change after an init phase? then do not bother with indicies. define a `struct Interesting`, that holds a pointer to the data and the values you are interested and make `interesting` an `std::vector<Interesting>`.

Comment: @user9400869 that would sort-of work, but I need to easily access the whole vector of `A` and `B` separately from `interesting` at times, and vice-versa. Also, because I have multiple properties ( `A` and  `B` ) the `struct` should hold both but that would waste memory as well since not every `interesting` has both!

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I didn't know about boost::multi_index and it's an interesting read but I'm afraid it's not what I'm searching for

Comment: std::unordered_map lookup is indeed O(1) although much slower then vector lookup since it requires hashing. The vector lookup on the other hand requires more memory. So as usual you have a tradeof. You either need speed or low memory hit. But you can't have both.

Comment: Thanks @freakish, I'll test unordered_map, map and the vector implementation. I suspect vector will still be fastest but there's a limit on how much memory I am willing to waste :)